# Comparing reflected collection types in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection

I have a reflected collection type I need to compare to see if it's a certain kind of collection.  How can I do that?

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = currentMirror.classSymbol(a.getClass).typeSignature
println("Q? "+ (b =:= typeOf[List[_]]))
```

This is always false, of course.  In practice I have a list of collections, generalized with _ .  I need to know if a given Type (typically specific in its parameters) is one of these collections.  For example I need to know if List[Int] is a List[_].

The actual case is this:  Map of generic type -> function for something I need:

```
val collectionHandlers = Map(
    typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.List[_]] -> fnList,
    typeOf[scala.collection.immutable.Map[_,_]] -> fnMap,
    //...
)
val aListType = // something here that is a TypeSignature of List[Int] as above
collectionHandlers( _magicClean(aListType) )()
```

Where _magicClean is what I need help with.  How to I "generalize" the specifically-typed collection so that map lookup will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `a`'s `classSymbol` is `::`. It also doesn't contain the type information for the contained type `Int` (the `toString` only shows generics).

Say, if we have a method like this:

```
def typeTagOf[A](a: A)(implicit tt: TypeTag[A]) = tt
```

We can use it to get the exact `Type` of `a`, and compare it with `typeOf[List[_]]`.

```
scala> typeTagOf(a).tpe <:< typeOf[List[_]]
res165: Boolean = true

scala> typeTagOf(1).tpe <:< typeOf[List[_]]
res166: Boolean = false
```

But it's *not* true that `List[Int]` is `List[_]`, which is why I used `<:<` instead of `=:=`. That is, a `List[Int]` is sub-type of a `List[_]`, but they are not exactly the same type. It's not really clear what you need this for. If you're only matching collection types (without the inner type), you can probably get away with using `List[_]`, etc. But there are caveats. For example, if you have this:

```
val list: List[_] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

You cannot recover the type information and prove it is a list of only `Int`s, because `_` is an existential type.

```
scala> typeTagOf(list)
res170: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[_$1]] forSome { type _$1 } = TypeTag[scala.List[_$1]]
```